# VMware Workstation - autostart shared VM for all users (non-admin users)

Tags: vmware-workstation

we have an issue where I set a virtual machine in VMware Workstation 12 to autostart. However, I logged in as the local admin to do so. When the enduser logs in, the VM does not autostart since it is already running in the other account. Is there a way to "bridge the gap" between the two user accounts so that the VM is seen running no matter who is logged in? I thought a "Shared VM" would do this, but apparently not..? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to use a batch file in the startup folder or taskscheduler ? E.g. with this command, vmware -x "C:\My virtual machine\yourVM.vmx" , adding your path from the account in which the vm resides.

Comment: I have not, good idea! I will try that, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shared VM that is configured to autostart will start when the host boots up; no user is required to log in.  Therefore, these statements:

> However, I logged in as the local admin to do so. When the enduser logs in, the VM does not autostart since it is already running in the other account.

make no sense.  Additionally, it's unclear what you mean by "does not autostart" when it's already started.

I'm presuming that you actually mean that your other user is not able to *access* that running VM.  Other users can access shared VMs via the "Shared VMs" node of the Workstation library.  If they can't, then they probably do not have permission to interact with the VM.  You can configure this (as an administrator) by opening the VM and choosing VM > Manage > Permissions, adding the local user, and assigning it a role (e.g. "VM User").

You also can right-click on the "Shared VMs" node of the library and choose "Permissions" from the context menu to set permissions that propagate to all shared VMs.

Be aware that shared VMs also will be network-accessible (but this can be restricted by configuring a firewall on your host and/or router).